# How can Arduino display the date as 08/01/18 instead of 08/01/2018?

Tags: datetime, arduino

How can I display the date as 08/01/18 instead of 08/01/2018 with this code?

```cpp
DateTime now;
char text1[5];
sprintf(text1, "%02hhu/%02hhu/%04hhu", now.day(), now.month(), now.year());
```

Comment: my code is working, it gives 08/01/2018 but I don't want the century

Comment: I know I can take substring of the String but I would like to know if there is a direct possibility to use sprintf or DateTime format to get the date in YY format

Comment: You would use modular arithmetic (like now.year() % 100) but you'll need at least 8 characters long char buffer since day/month/year takes 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Celal, this works:

```cpp
DateTime now;
char text1[8];
sprintf(text1, "%02hhu/%02hhu/%04hhu", now.day(), now.month(), now.year()%100);
```